# converting from PriorityQueue to ArrayList

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to convert this Best First Search algorithm from using PriorityQueue to ArrayList since they are both Java's collection classes 
here is my main in case you guys want to take a look at it

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Main {

/* Create the open and closed lists */
private static Comparator<Board> comparator = new BoardComparator();
private static PriorityQueue<Board> open = 
        new PriorityQueue<Board>(10, comparator);
private static Closed closed = new Closed();

/* Declare variables that will be used for 
 * purposes of processing the lists and generating
 * child board objects.
 */
private static Board b;
private static int board [][] = new int[4][4];       
private static int cboard1 [][] = new int [4][4];
private static int cboard2 [][] = new int [4][4];
private static String id = new String();
private static int cost = 0;
private static int depth;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    /* Create the root board object*/
    Board root = new Board ();

    run(root);
}

/* Uses the best-first-search algorithm to solve the NQueens puzzle */
public static void run(Board root) {

    /* Enqueue the root board object on the open and closed lists */  
    open.add(root);
    closed.add(root);

    /* While the open list isn't empty */
    while (open.size() != 0){

        /* Dequeue a board object from the open list and 
         * get its depth, cost and the actual board */
        b = open.remove();
        cost = b.getG();   
        depth = b.getH();
        board = b.getBoard();

        /* If the cost of the dequeued a board object is 
         * equal to 0, end processing */
        if (cost == 0){
            System.out.println("\nGoal Achieved ...");
            b.displayBoard();
            System.out.println(b.toString());
            break;
        }

        /* Display the contents of the board object */
        System.out.println("\nEvaluating Board ...");
        b.displayBoard();
        System.out.println(b.toString());

        enumerateChildren();

    }
}

/* Enumerates the next set of child board objects in the graph */
public static void enumerateChildren() {

    /* Get the depth for the child board objects */
    depth += 1;

    System.out.println("\nGenerating Children ...");
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){            
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++){

            /* If the current element is a queen */
            if (board[i][j] == 1){

                /* Copy board and remove the queen from the copies */
                cboard1 = Board.copyBoard(board);
                cboard2 = Board.copyBoard(board);
                cboard1[i][j] = 0;
                cboard2[i][j] = 0;

                if (j == 0){

                    /* If the queen was in the first column, move it
                     * one element to the right and process the child board
                     */                             
                    cboard1[i][j+1] = 1;    
                    processChild(cboard1);

                } else if ((j == 1) || (j == 2)){

                    /* If the queen was in the second or third columns, move it
                     * one element to the right and one element to the left, and
                     * process the child boards
                     */ 
                    cboard1[i][j-1] = 1;
                    cboard2[i][j+1] = 1;
                    processChild(cboard1);
                    processChild(cboard2);                        

                } else {

                    /* If the queen was in the fourth column, move it
                     * one element to the left and process the child board
                     */  
                    cboard1[i][j-1] = 1;
                    processChild(cboard1);            
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}

/* Processes each of the child board objects that has been enumerated */
public static void processChild(int board[][]){

    /* Get id and cost of board */
    id = Board.getId(board);
    cost = Board.evaluateBoard(board);

    /* Create a board Object */
    Board b = new Board (board, id, depth, cost);

    /* If the board object isn't on the closed
     * list, enqueue it on the open and closed lists
     */
    if (!closed.isReviewed(b)){
        open.add(b);
        closed.add(b);

        b.displayBoard();
        System.out.println(b.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: List<?> list = new ArrayList<>( myQueue );

Comment: Thank you! I've tried this way before and I face an issue with getting the adding and removing methods to work . 2

Comment: @e201611 What do you mean "face an issue with getting the adding and removing methods to work"?

Comment: @xtratic if you look thorough the code you will see that I'm using a remove method that dequeue a Board object. when I tried casting the priorityqueue to an ArrayList like the way suggested the add and remove methods didn't worked because the remove method requires a parameter

Comment: @e201611 Why do you want to switch to `ArrayList` if that data structure doesn't fit your design like the queue does?

Comment: @xtratic it does fits and I think using an ArrayList would make the algorithm more efficient when searching for the goal

Comment: @e201611 Why are you using a `PriorityQueue` in the first place then?

Comment: @xtratic don't we as programmers develop and try things out infinitely ?

Comment: @e201611 No.. no we don't, we don't have infinite time, we try the things that make sense to our design. Considering what data structure to use is an important design decision. If there was no reason for a queue, then you can simply switch to an array list and iterate over your permutations of the board.

Answer (score 0):

They might be both `Collection`s, but that doesn't mean they're similar. A `HashSet` is also a `Collection`, and you can't expect your code to work with that.

I'm guessing the code depends on `PriorityQueue`'s capability of ordering the elements based on their priority, so replacing it with a normal `List` (or any other `Collection`) won't work.

Comment: True, and that's why I decided to seek help from this community